# Bootstrap Grid columns

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying this code to divide columns, but i am unable to divide. colors are not important

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-2" style="background: red;height: 20vh;"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-6" style="background: blue;height: 20vh;"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-4" style="background: pink;height: 50vh;"></div> 
 </div>
<div class="row"> 
    <div class="col-sm-5" style="background: green;height: 20vh;"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-3" style="background: red;height: 20vh;"></div>

</div>
```

my expected output is:

[image: grid]

Comment: Your colours don't match - difficult to tell exactly what you want

Comment: You need to divide the initial row into two **columns* and have rows inside that.

Comment: colors can be anything sir.

Comment: Yes, but in your representation of what you want, it's difficult to tell which `col` matches up with which.

Comment: You mean, something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/ur3c8pv9/2/ . Is that what you need?